# Big $\mathcal{O}$ Notation $f(N)=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

If $f(N)=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right)$ (the big-oh) means that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ grows faster than $f(N)$ as $N \to \infty$. So it is possible to take $f(N)=\frac{1}{N}$ or  $f(N)=\frac{1}{N^2}$.

Am I correct ?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily *grow* at all (as you see here), and in any regard not strictly *faster*, but rather it does bound from above (up to multiplication by constant) all but finitely many elements. That is, $\limsup\frac{f(N)}{1/\sqrt{N}}$ is finite. Indeed, both functions you describe have this property.

Answer (score 1):

When you say $f(N) = \mathcal{O} \left( g(N) \right)$ this means that $f(N)$ is equal to some function that has the property

$$
f(N) \leq c g(N)
$$

for all $N \geq N_0$, and $c$ some constant. In your case this means that there's an $N_0$ and constant $c$ for which

$$f(N) \leq \frac{c}{\sqrt{N}}.$$

Therefore your choices are both valid as candidates for $f(N)$, but trivially even $f(N) = 0$ is a suitable candidate.

Comment: Thank you. That's the problem. We can select many valid functions for $f(N)$. I noticed that usually people take directly $M_{n}= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ? is it becose its the worst case ?

Comment: I don't know what's your application. The things usually work in the following way, you have some kind of recurrence that you want to solve, because the solution in closed form is sometimes complicated you at least "try to guess" the class of that function. It's not the other way around (where you know the class and you pick one function of that class). Not sure I've answered to your question.

Comment: However if the case is that you know the class, you can pick any function that belongs to that set.

Answer (score -1):

By definition

> $$f(x) = \mathcal{O}(g(x)) \iff f(x) \leq cg(x)$$

In your case let $f(N)=\dfrac{1}{N^a}$ with $a \in \mathbb{N} $  and $\,g(N)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, then 
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{f(N)}{cg(N)} = \frac{\frac{1}{N^a}}{\frac{c}{\sqrt{N}}} = \frac{\sqrt{N}}{cN^a} = \sqrt{\frac{N}{(cN^a)^2}}= \frac{1}{cN^{\frac{a2-1}{2}}} =0 $$
Therefore
$$f(N) \leq \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{N}}\implies f(N) = \mathcal{O}\left(g(N)\right) $$
$\tag*{$\Box$}$
So you're right.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting answers.

Comment: @LinaHam you are welcome.

Comment: Your "Note" at the end is wrong. They are **not** equivalent. It is true that $\lim f/g = c \geq 0 \implies f = O(g)$, but the converse is false.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank for your comment!. I have edited the answer